# CKEditor Respond to Cancel of a Specific Dialog Instance

Tags: events, dialog, ckeditor, cancel-button

The following simple code creates two CKEditor editors.  The cancel event function detects and responds to the cancel event of the image dialog regardless of the editor launching the dialog, which, given its semantics, makes sense. And it works (the alert launches on any image dialog but no others, like link dialogs).  However, I want to detect and respond to the cancel event of the image dialog on one and only one of the editors (in my case editor1). I cannot figure out, after much googling and searching the CKEditor API documentation, the proper semantics for doing so.  I am using CKEditor 4.5.1.

```
<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {});
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (e)
{
    var dialogName = e.data.name;
    if (dialogName != 'image') return;
    var dialog = e.data.definition.dialog;
    dialog.on('cancel', function ()
    {
        alert("do something");
    });
});
</script>
<textarea id="editor2" name="editor2"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
CKEDITOR.replace('editor2', {});
</script>
```

Can someone please tell me how to limit the response to the dialog opened by a specific editor?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I could add this code, but it would be a hack.  Looking for something more direct, and better.    var editorName = e.editor.name;
  if (editorName != 'editor1') return;

Comment: No responses.  Went with the hack mentioned above.  It works.